# despite state change component is not re-rendering in react native?

Tags: react-native

i am a react native beginner and struggling with re-rendering a component despite state change, here is the omitted version of my component:

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { getItem } = useAsyncStorage("todo");
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  function renderCard({ item }) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onLongPress={() => {
          setSelectedItems((selectedItems) => [...selectedItems, item.title]);
        }}
        underlayColor="gray"
      >
        <Card
          style={
            selectedItems.includes(item.title)
              ? styles.cardSelected
              : styles.cardNotSelected
          }
        >
          <Card.Title style={styles.cardTitle}>{item.title}</Card.Title>
        </Card>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", getTodoList);

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        refreshing={loading}
        onRefresh={getTodoList}
        style={styles.list}
        data={items}
        renderItem={renderCard}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardSelected: {
    backgroundColor: "#444333",
  },
  cardNotSelected: {
    backgroundColor: "#ff2f2f",
  },
});
```

I basically want to change background color of a Card when a card is longpressed, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Re-rendering was fine, background color setting was wrong.

Instead of:

```
<Card
      style={
        selectedItems.includes(item.title)
          ? styles.cardSelected
          : styles.cardNotSelected
      }
>
```

I needed to use `containerStyle` to change the background of the card:

```
<Card
      containerStyle={
        selectedId === item.id
          ? styles.cardSelected
          : styles.cardNotSelected
      }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
  {…otherProps}
  extraData={selectedItems}
/>
```

Use the [extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) prop. It will cause the FlatList to re render when the values provided changes

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. I am able to console.log(selectedItems) and see the updated list but it is not triggering re-render.